# Project management SW supports cross-project dependencies and escalation

Tags: project-management, dependencies

I need a project and task management software that supports linking dependencies between tasks from different projects (I can link a task that depends on other task in another project.)

Also, it supports escalation; if the task is not finished on the specified date, a notification is sent to X. And if not finished after ... days a notification is sent to Y.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is Microsoft Project. This software can make related between projects and from there [make dependencies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-and-update-task-dependencies-links-across-projects-a69dfdd8-efaa-4157-b53a-a294cf466298) between tasks in those projects. Also you can [set alerts/notifications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-email-reminders-about-your-work-in-project-web-app-2372c181-1c98-416a-9306-ac28f027334b) about different changes in the projects. The question is how you define if task is finished or not. Is this hand work or some automated process.

Be aware most of the time those things are not so sample as point and click.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. Please an you enrich it with links that could guide me to know the way to achieve it. Thank you once again.

Comment: @CSStudent, check my updated answer

Comment: That was extremely helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you are still looking, but I would recommend taking a look at [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/project-management/).

It allows you to draw dependencies between tasks in different projects and then review them in a Portfolio Gantt view for easier management. So, the visualization is there as well as the feature itself.

Regarding the notifications, you can add watchers to your tasks, meaning they are not responsible for delivering the task but get all the notifications related to it. So it is easier to track the progress of everything that matters.